# type=meeting for all events

Tags: trigger

I have a requirement where I want to put `type=='meeting'` for all the events
type has a picklist data type where meeting is a value

Here is the trigger I have written but it is not working.

```
trigger FieldUpdaterofEvent on Event (before insert,before update) {
    list<event> toUpdate = new list <event>();
    for(Event eve:trigger.new){
        if(eve.type=='--None--'){
            eve.type='Meeting';
            toUpdate.add(eve);
        }
    }
    update toUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want all event records whose `Type` is not set, to be created with `Type` as `Meeting`.

This can be done by setting the **default value** to `Meeting` on the `Type` picklist field.

If you still want to do it by trigger, then this is how your trigger should be

```
trigger FieldUpdaterofEvent on Event (before insert,before update) {
    for(Event eve:trigger.new){
        if(string.isBlank(eve.type)){
            eve.type='Meeting';
        }
    }
}
```

- As you are writing the trigger for before insert and before update event, all the records won't be committed to database yet, hence you don't have to write explicit DML statements for it.
- When comparing the picklist value, you will have to check it against `''` or `null` (You can use `String.isBlank` or `String.isEmpty`) and not `--None--`, unless you have `--None--` as a picklist value which I doubt.

Comment: line `list<event> toUpdate = new list <event>();` is superfluous

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, corrected it

Comment: thanks a lot and could please help me with this also Activity Score on Contact and Account should be updated based on following formula.

Contact/Account Activity Score = 
Count of Meetings * 3 + Count of calls * 2 + Count of Emails * 1

Note: This count will be done for all child activities

Comment: what should i do with it